# Close Working File on Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the keyboard shortcut for closing a working file in VS Code on a Mac?

When I issue the default <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, it sometimes closes the entire IDE, or alternatively blanks the screen, but the file is still in the "Working Files" list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press `Cmd+W` (or `Ctrl+W` on Windows) you are actually closing the editor area. If you have more than one editor area open, you can reduce the number of areas until all are closed. Pressing it again in that state will close the window.

Beginning with version 0.5.0 we added new commands that you can use to close a working file or all working files. The keybinding is be `Cmd+K W` or `Ctrl+K W` on Windows.